# appending parameter using mod_rewrite according to the subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am fairly new to using mod_rewrite and I have been digging through various questions and documentation files without getting a solution.

People can access my site using one of 2 hosts:

```
www.example.com
fr.example.com
```

The subdomain indicates the language of the user.
If www is used, the language should assumed to be English.

What I am trying to do is detect the subdomain and pass its value as a parameter to the original request.

Here is what I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

# match the subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fr.example.com$ [NC]

# Make sure I don't already have a "lang" in the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang= [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) $1?lang=fr [QSA] 

# match the subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]

# Make sure I don't already have a "lang" in the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang= [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) $1?lang=en [QSA]
```

I am testing this by going to:
    http://fr.example.com/index.php?a=1
In index.php I am dumping the content of the request parameters, but I keep getting:

```
array ( 'a' => '1', )
```

I WAS expecting to see:

```
array ( 'a' => '1', 'lang' => 'fr)
```

I am using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to debug my rules, but I can't get myself to resolve this issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

FIrst thing first don't use `http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/` test as that is very reliable. Better to test on your localhost.

Now your rules also need correction. Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# match the subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fr\.example\.com$ [NC]
# Make sure I don't already have a "lang" in the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?lang=fr [L,QSA] 

# match the subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
# Make sure I don't already have a "lang" in the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?lang=en [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer, but this doesn't solve my problem.
For some reason, I don't get the lang parameter to get appended.
I just get the original request....

Answer (score 0):

If you have other languages that you may add later, you can make it a little more dynamic. So if it is www or non www it will be `en`, if it is anything else, it can append according. That's another way you can do it.

```
RewriteEngine On 

#match en domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?lang=en [QSA,L]

#match other languages (subdomains)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?lang=1% [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is not working...
I test this by going to:
http://fr.example.com/test.php?a=b (I have the hosts file altered on my computer to direct example.com to 127.0.0.1)
In page test.php I print the request. Instead of getting:

Comment: Youre not testing this on a live box? You have to simulate dns so you need to add fr.example.com and www.example.com to host file also because those are all different hostnames